# Remove AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list divider

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, divider, dropdownlistfor

In my application, I'm using AutoCompleteTextView.
One of the requirements is to hide the divider.
I have added AutoCompleteTextView to layout:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@id/address_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/address_operation_btn"
android:background="@null"
android:completionThreshold="1"
android:dropDownAnchor="@id/anchor"
android:dropDownVerticalOffset="13dp"
android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:hint="@string/address_bar_hint"
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
android:inputType="textUri"
android:maxLines="1"
android:saveEnabled="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:dropDownListViewStyle="@style/searchResultsList"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textColorHint="#80FFFFFF"
android:textSize="17sp" />
```

The style i'm using is

```
    <style name="searchResultsList" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
</style>
```

But the divider is still there...
How if can be hidden?

Comment: http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html this example might help

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example this too

Answer (score 11):

Override it with your application theme. In your `themes.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
  <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:dividerHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Credits to: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/11/styling-autocompletetextview.html

Comment: 2023 and this still works. thanks!