# Android - Customize SearchView suggestions divider

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, searchview, divider, theming

I am trying to customize a `SearchView` in `ActionBar`. The last thing remaining is to set the suggestion dropdown divider color. Early on I found out, that for some unimaginable reason, one does not simply style `SearchView`, most of the stuff is styleable in runtime only and you have to google many different hacks to achieve the look you want.

I use the AppCompat version, however I think the process is very similar. First I retrieve my `SearchView`:

```
searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
```

I found out in source codes, that the dropdown is hidden inside some internal extension of `AutoCompleteTextView`, however, still accessible via its ID like this:

```
AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Now the next task was to style the divider inside of the `AutoCompleteTextView`. The problem is that the AutoCompleteTextView itself is a `TextView` that contains ListPopupWindow inside (see the mPopup variable in the source code of [AutoCompleteTextView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3bdbf644d61f46b531838558fabbd5b990fc4913/core/java/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java)), which finally has the desired `getListView` method, and ListView has `setDivider` and `setDividerHeight` methods that I really really want to use. But the ListPopupWindow is created in runtime and shown only on demand, and it's a private member, so I don't know how to access it.

So once again, the simplified structure is `ActionBar > SearchView > AutoCompleteTextView > ListPopupWindow > ListView`. I have found way around all the arrows but one (`AutoCompleteTextView` > `ListPopupWindow`).

Other alternative is to style it using XML, but as I mentioned earlier on, styling `ActionBar` and especially `SearchView` is very troublesome and I don't really know how to do it from reading the source code.

Only thing I found using Google was to set all the dropdown dividers in theme (e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359249/remove-autocompletetextview-dropdown-list-divider)), but it does not apply to the `SearchView` dropdown and I have no idea why.

Anyone who can help me at least with a bit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally found out that it was much simpler to change the whole theme from Holo.Light.DarkActionBar to Holo.Light, since the color of the divider is already okay there, I just had to style the ActionBar to the Dark version, but that was pretty easy, took about 20 minutes :)

Comment: Hi, my problem is the suggestion list background is dark and have no divider at all. I can change the background color but no solution for divider . I have tried your solution without luck.

Comment: Hi, I did not solve it either, I just used Holo.Light theme, where the suggestion list was okay. Also note, that this was using Appcompat v7/API 19. My final recommendation is not to rely too much on support API libraries, because it just sucks.

If you are keen to solve this, I found out the divider is in fact a private member of some inner component, therefore you can actually track it and then change its visibility via reflection. Yes, I saw someone doing that. You don't really want to do this :D