# How can I remove divider from dropdown in multiautocompletetextview in android in TokenAutoComplete

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete. I am unable to remove divider and set `autocompletetextview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

I tried :

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyListViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
    </style>
```

and also

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>
    </style>
```

Layout file:

```
<com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="name"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"


        android:dropDownListViewStyle="@style/MyTheme"

        />
```

But its not working .How can I remove divider and enable hardware for displaying dotted lines in multiautocompletetextview dropdown? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: where have you used these styles?

Comment: android:dropDownListViewStyle="@style/MyTheme" in 
    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView     is this correct?

Comment: post that layout file in your question

Comment: updated my Q .. Need anything else??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list divider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359249/remove-autocompletetextview-dropdown-list-divider)

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359249/remove-autocompletetextview-dropdown-list-divider) will help you.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I have tried it before posting this .Also my code is the same. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

in second way remove @null with:

```
 <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: replace it <item name="android:divider">@null</item>